# Rewrite only images with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm trying to make the following kind of mapping from URL to file system **for image files only**:

```
mysite.com/image.jpg  ->  images/image.jpg
mysite.com/folder/other.jpg  ->  images/folder/other.jpg
mysite.com/x/y/z.jpg  ->  images/x/y/z.jpg
```

I've tried the following, but it apparently causes an infinite redirect loop:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any mod_rewrite gurus here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a condition before your rule to see if it has already been rewritten to images/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I would suggest the QSA flag could likely be removed as it's unlikely you'll have a query string following the image URI.

Comment: Thanks, it works that way! Also, the QSA flag was unnecessary.